# Error while migrating controllers on my Laravel 8 project

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, rollback

I'm working on my project of my university following a course of Laravel 8. I have all fine but in a moment, the teacher said to write the command: `php artisan migrate:fresh -seed` and my tables of permissions, roles and roleHasPermissions was deleted (I'm using Spatie), I don't know why, but I'm searching to create again these tables but I'm typing `php artisan migrate` and now appears this error:

```
    Migrating: 2022_05_15_135154_create_providers_table

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'providers' already exists (SQL: create table `providers` (`id` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `name` varchar(255) not null, `businessName` varchar(255) not null, `rut` varchar(255) not null, `adress` varchar(255) not null, `city` varchar(255) not null, `country` varchar(255) not null, `phone` varchar(255) not null, `email` varchar(255) not null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\crud_habibi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:742
    738▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    739▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a   
    740▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    741▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 742▕             throw new QueryException(
    743▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    744▕             );
    745▕         }
    746▕     }

  1   C:\xampp\htdocs\crud_habibi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:527
      PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'providers' already exists")

  2   C:\xampp\htdocs\crud_habibi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:527
      PDOStatement::execute()
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
php artisan migrate:fresh
```

it may works